# Is there a way I can control the class of the button using button_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sass

It seems that :class appears to control the class of the parent form, not the button itself.

I want to add the class `btn primary` to the button.

If I can't do it directly, can I do it using the form class and SASS? (using @extend or something similar)?

Comment: Are you using Rails 3.0 or 3.1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure that `:class => "btn primary"` is the third argument of the `button_to` call.

If you're doing this:

```
<%= button_to "Hello", :action => :new, :class => "btn primary" %>
```

You are actually saying:

```
<%= button_to("Hello", { :action => :new, :class => "btn primary" }) %>
```

So you should change it to:

```
<%= button_to "Hello", { :action => :new }, :class => "btn primary" %>
```

I try to avoid using hashes for paths altogether, and use the generated routing methods.

```
<%= button_to "Hello", new_hello_path, :class => "btn primary" %>
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it

```
<%= button_to 'New Job', {:controller => :jobs, :action => :new}, :class => 'btn primary' %>
```